# Is there a way to include timezone information in a select query?

Tags: postgresql

I have these queries

```
CREATE TABLE times (
  time TIMESTAMP
);

insert into times values(now());
select * from times;
          time            
---------------------------
2021-01-05 15:25:55.170
(1 row)
```

What I would like is this timestamp formatted with UTC similar to how java formats UTC timestamps (java.time.Instant.now()) `2021-01-05T15:25:55.170Z`.

and what I could do is manually format the string like so

```
select replace(time::text, ' ', 'T') || 'Z' from times;
```

but is there a more conventional / cleaner way of achieving this timestamp format?

Comment: [Don't use `TIMESTAMP` but `TIMESTAMPTZ` for this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9571392/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
select to_char('2021-01-05 15:25:55.170'::timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.MST')|| 'Z';
         ?column?          
---------------------------
 2021-01-05T15:25:55.170TZ
```

For more information on formatting see [Data formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-formatting.html).